# Question about the "Getting Started with BigQuery ML" excercise

Tags: machine-learning

Did somebody work on this exercise ? It is a way to estimate transaction in JUNE 2017. 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bqml-intro/index.html#0

When we compare orders JUNE 2017 prediction (step6) versus reality (meaning what we have in BQ), the difference is quite important (more than 50%) - do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a single datapoint may not be the best way to evaluate the model performance.

Please start with reviewing the output of ML.Evaluate to understand how the model is behaving overall.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @girishkumar, comparing a single datapoint may not be the best way to evaluate the model performance; at the same time, please consider that the purpose of the codelab is to show how BigQuery ML works.

However, I replicated the lab and observed that if you remove the limit of the SQL statement in the step 4 you got better results in the model evaluation step.

By last, if you are interested in learning how to use this tool, you can try [the following tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/tutorials).